# Firebase - fetch only elements with specified key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How am I able to fetch only elements with specified key?

In my case I have n of entries by users. If the entry is new - it's unverified and I dont want it to be fetched by other users (I dont want it to display on users screen).

So until the entry is verified, it has to be invisible.

Let's say that each entry contains a flag `isVerified` which is `false` by default. After verification it changes to `true`.

How to tell firebase to fetch only these entries with `true` as value of `isVerified` key?

Tried queries, but failed. It should be something like `ref.orderByChild('isVerified').isTruthy` or so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [equalTo()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#equalTo) to retrieve values with child property `isVerified` equal to `true`. This would need to be done in combination with and ordering function such as [orderByChild()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#orderByChild)

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref("foobar");
ref.orderByChild("isVerified").equalTo(true).once("value", function(snapshot) {
  /// ... do something with snapshot
});
```

Firebase has helpful documentation/examples regarding [sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Hopefully that helps!